# Se pueden borrar variables en python. ¿¿Pero como?

Tags: python, variables, eliminar

Mi duda es si se podrían borrar variables de un código en Python que ya no tengan utilidad. Sin usar `del`.

Comment: x = 'variable' del x Referencia
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement

Comment: si no sabes la sintaxis puedes leer la documentacion

Comment: Las variables locales a una función desaparecen automáticamente al terminar ésta. Organiza tu código en funciones y no tendrás necesidad de preocuparte de borrar variables.

Comment: @nadie estás empeorando tu pregunta, ¡ahora es demasiado ambigua!

Comment: `del` no borra el dato, solo borra la referencia a él (el nombre de la variable). Ahora bien, si la referencia que borras es la única que quedaba apuntando al dato, entonces el recolector de basura eliminará el dato de memoria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que python hace uso de un concepto conocido como [garbage collector](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.htm), quien es el encargado de liberar la memoria relacionada con todos aquellos objetos que ya no estan siendo referenciados (en otras palabras, son inaccesible o dejaron de ser usados).

Hay varias formas de que una referencia a un objeto sea eliminada, la más común es por que el flujo del código salio del bloque de código donde la variable fue creada. Otra forma de hacerlo es a través de `del nombre_variable` sin embargo ninguno de los anteriores casos forza al **garbage collector** a reclamar la memoria relacionada con dichos objetos, simplemente los objetos son marcados como listos para liberar. Para forzar la liberación de la memoria debes marcar como libre el objeto con `del` y posteriormente forzar un llamado al **garbage collector** con `gc.collect()` resultando en:

```py
import gc

variable = 1
del variable
gc.collect()
```

La manipulación directa del **garbage collector** no debe ser utilizada a menos que sea realmente necesario, la prinicipal razón es por que la liberación de memoria es un proceso periódico realizado por el intérprete que no es realizado cada vez que se marca como liberado un objeto, esto debido a que el proceso de liberación de objetos es más complicado de lo que parece (pueden existir objetos que se hacen referencia a si mismos pero que no tienen ninguna referencia exterior), resultando en un proceso tardado que es disparado por python solo cuando él lo cree adecuado.